# Help find a novel with a female heroine from, at latest 1990 in a two part novel?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel back in junior high so around 1989 that was a fantasy novel with a female heroine.  All I remember is that I think it was 2 book series.  Once when the heroine was young and then again when she is older.  I believe the story opens with her working in a tavern, maybe something to do with belly dancing and then something happens to take her away from her life into an adventure where I believe she has powers.

I always thought the author was a female but I could be wrong as well.  I also remember in the library it was in the first section of the books so the last name was closer to the front of the alphabet.

Any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a reach, but you could be talking about the first two books in the [P C Hodgell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._C._Hodgell) series the 'God Stalker Chronicles'.

The main character is a girl often remembered for her rather interesting fingernails (more closely related to claws) and some powers that she, at least at first, doesn't understand.  Early in the series, she works at a tavern/public house, and for at least some time, as a rather hypnotic dancer.

There is a [Wiki](http://kencyr.wikia.com/wiki/Kencyr_Wiki) for the series, but it doesn't seem terribly helpful for basic details.  [Here's a link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439133360) to an Amazon re-issue of the first two books together.

Comment: [Here's a link to the publisher's website](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-873-the-god-stalker-chronicles.aspx), where you can get a DRM-free e-book version (and read sample chapters before you buy).

Comment: However, as of five books in, she still hasn't returned to the Res aB'tyrr, the tavern that she worked, and danced, at.

Comment: Side note, she came back in the ninth book. Her luck with cities burning/crumbling in her wake continues...

Answer (score 1):

Time frame works for Mercedes Lackey's "The Lark and the Wren", her first book in the Bardic Voices series.  Might have had the second book out at that time.  No belly dancing I am afraid, but she plays as a musician in her fathers tavern.  She leaves and develops the powers Bards have through music.

Comment: That was a great series.  Robin and the Kestrel was good too.